# Get nested associated records in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **I have three Database Tables.**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblprojecttype` (
  `ProjectTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tblprojecttypecurrencyprice` (
  `ProjectTypeCurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tblcurrency` (
  `CurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### **Models**

```
class Currency_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblcurrency";
    protected $primaryKey = "CurrencyID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}

class ProjectType_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojecttype";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectTypeID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function projecttypecurrencyprice()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model', 
                                                     "ProjectTypeID");
    }
}

class ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojecttypecurrencyprice";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectTypeCurrencyID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Currency()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Currency_Model', "CurrencyID");
    }
}
```

**There is `CurrencyID` relationship and `ProjectTypeID` relationship**

### **What I am trying ?**

In my Laravel 5.1 code, I am trying to achive below sql statement so that I can get `projecttypecurrencyprice records` for each `ProjectType record`. Finally it should also show records from `currency Table` for each  `projecttypecurrencyprice`  record

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
                ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice")
                ->with("projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency")
                ->get();
```

### **What's the Problem ?**

I am not able to get Currency records for each projecttypecurrencyprice record.

Comment: Could you paste your models? The part where you define relations to other mentioned models

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model` you should change `Currency` relationship this way:

```
public function Currency()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Currency_Model', "CurrencyID");
}
```

because you have `CurrencyId` column in `tblprojecttypecurrencyprice` and you don't have any connection to `ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model` in `tblcurrency`.
And to get data instead of:

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
                ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice")
                ->with("projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency")
                ->get();
```

you can omit 1st `with`:

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
                ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency")
                ->get();
```

By the way if you start this project, you should consider changes in your database structure and read about PSR in PHP - you should rather not use `ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model` as your model name if you really don't have to, same for `ProjectTypeID` columns in MySQL